# How global variables to be accessed in multi-thread env?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, properties

How global variables to be accessed in multi-thread env? Eg: the following messageServerUrl variable how to keep it thread safe? Is it atomic enough to keep safe? If not, any other solution available? Any idea please share, thanks in advance.

@property(atomic, copy) NSString * messageServerUrl;

Comment: BTW - `messageServerUrl` is not a global variable. It is a property. Each instance of the class has its own copy of the property.

Comment: @rmaddy Well, it's global to all the methods in the instance regardless of what thread they are running on. And indeed, in a deeper sense, the variable isn't even a property; it's an instance variable. "property" just means there's an accessor method for that instance variable.

Comment: @matt A property doesn't require an instance variable. Of course there is one in most cases but not always. And the term "global variable" typically  has a different meaning than instance variables or properties.

Comment: @rmaddy Agreed; my point exactly. Since "a property doesn't require an instance variable" then there is even less sense in phrase "each instance of the class has its own copy of the property". There's no there there.

Comment: Sorry for not explain clearly, messageServerUrl is a variable in my singleton instance, will be accessed globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`atomic` doesn't magically keep something thread-safe. It just makes a thread-safe accessor method.

Being very very very careful is what makes a shared value safe (and sometimes not even that!). You could still mess up your life seriously if you accessed the same value from two different threads in a way that puts your logic at risk.

If you know, for example, that this value is set before the secondary thread kicks off, and all you ever do after that is use the getter, then yes, that's probably safe.

But the safest way to share data between multiple threads is: don't. If the data doesn't need to be changed, then pass it to the secondary thread at the outset. This is why GCD is so wonderful: it's serial queues by default, plus you keep passing the data down into the block executed on the next thread, so you get effective locking without locks (which are easy to mismanage).

Comment: Thanks. Agree with you, if that variable is read only then OK for multi-thread env, otherwise using lock is the best method.

Comment: The book <Effective objective C> also recommends serial GCD solution to keep its atomatic characteristic.

Comment: And so does my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch38.html#_grand_central_dispatch